# Uploading an image to Twitter or Facebook and not losing quality (like Temple Run 2)?

Tags: ios

Every time I upload an image to Twitter or Facebook through my iOS app, the quality of the image is pretty poor. I've looked for this problem and it seems that everybody suffers it... except the people that made Temple Run 2. If you take a look at the image posted though the game:

https://twitter.com/MattGoldenVP/status/356082804066488320

It look great. How do they do this?

Answer (score 0):

Given the provided info, it's a first guess what might cause this:

Intermediate caches (aka proxies) are allowed to cache a different representation of the  given media type than the original. Thus, they may choose to compress it to save cache space or to reduce transfer times when the connection is bad.

Fortunately, HTTP 1.1 has recognized possible issues with this behavior and has introduced a means to let the sender specify a particular cache control header which actually forbids the proxies to touch the media they transfer:

If you specify the HTTP 1.1 header

`Cache-Control: no-transform`

you explicitly disallow to apply conversions to the media type while it is passed through proxies.

See also [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)
**14.9 Cache-Control** and 
**14.9.5 No-Transform Directive**

Comment: And how can we change the header from the Twitter/Facebook API of iOS?

Comment: Not using Apple's Twitter API  ;)